# events.js174 // unhandled 'error' event (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21) When connecting to FTP location

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp

I have a FTP location where files are updated twice daily, I dont know when these files are updated. I have attempted to create a node scrip that checks if files have changed. I am getting an error however. Which is below.

```sh
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.onerror (/Users/pb/Developer/ftp-crawler/node_modules/ftp/lib/connection.js:280:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

This is still work in progress...I would just like to understand why I am unable to connect. I am using the correct creds within the `config` object.

I believe I could be refused a connection by the FTP but I am not sure where or how to handle that error event...

Once connected I would like to check for files and check for size difference and any file that is higher in size should be downloaded.

This is my code

```
const Client = require('ftp');
const fs = require('fs');
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const c = new Client();

// get user name and password from user input.
const questions = [
    {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'un',
        message: 'Please enter your username:',
        validate: function(value) {
            if (value.length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'Please enter your username!';
            }
        }
    },
    {
        type: 'password',
        name: 'pw',
        message: 'Please enter your password:',
        validate: function(value) {
            if (value.length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'Please enter your password!';
            }
        }
    }
];

inquirer
    .prompt(questions)
    .then(answers => {
        // create a config object storing users inputted answers
        const config = {
            user: answers.un,
            password: answers.pw
        };

        config.host = `ftp://${config.user}:${
            config.password
        }_domainFtp@ftp.domain.com`;

        console.log(JSON.stringify(config.host));

        // connect to FTP
        c.connect(config.host);

        // check location for new files uploaded by date
        c.on('ready', function() {
            console.log('ready');

            const files = [];

            // get a directory listing of currrent working directory.
            // and append to files array so we can loop through to check sizes.
            c.list(function(error, list) {
                if (error) throw error;
                list.append(files);
                console.log(files);
            });

            // loop through files array to check file size change
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const stats = fs.statSync(files[i]);
                const fileSize = stats.size;

                if (fileSize > fileSize) {
                    // if file size differs download remote file and save it to the local file system:
                    c.get(files[i], function(error, stream) {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        stream.once('close', function() {
                            c.end();
                        });
                        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(files[i]));
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: So the FTP server is on the same machine as the script? (If that's always the case you could just use local file operations)

Comment: 1. `config.host = "ftp.domain.com";` 2. `c.connect(config);` (works for me right away)

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG I am getting a different error now but it's an error id expect. Even though the url format is `ftp://${config.user}:${config.password}_domainFtp@ftp.domain.com` are you still suggesting to use `ftp@domain.com` only in config.host?

Comment: Definitely, you were providing not the host but a full URI. If the password needs to have `_domainFtp` appended to it, you need `password: answers.pw + "_domainFtp"`. The format is `ftp://user:password@host:port` and you need to state all that info separately as part of the `config` object you're passing to the `connect()` call.

Comment: so like the following: `const config = {
   user: answers.un,
   password: answers.pw + '_domainFtp'
  };

  config.host = '@ftp.domain.com';`